# Unity3d - How to freeze a Animation in the Editor

Tags: unity

Is it possible to freeze my Animation in the Editor at a specific frame?

I made a simple camera animation, I try to select a specific frame inside of that animation and pause it, so I can work in the editor with everything positioned at the current positions at that specific frame.

This does not work at the moment. If I select my desired frame and then select another object, then my animation is set to start again.

This makes it very hard to work in the editor and prepare the animation.

---

**EDIT:**

Ok I try to explain it more simple. Let's assume I am animating the main camera and I have three animation points, A, B, and C.  (I know I have more, but lets just assume it for this example to simplify it)

At **A** the camera is obviously at the start position:

[image: A]

At at **B** it is somewhere in between A and C:

[image: Between A and C]

At **C** the camera is at the end position:
[image]

What I need is to pause the animation at **B**, so my animation object stays at this position the whole time, even though when it has no focus and another object is selected. This would make it much easier for me to place objects exactly where I need them.

What actually happens is that my animated object (maincamera) is set to it's "start position", but I need it to stay in place, so I can place other objects perfectly.

I hope that was clear enough.

[image: D]

(side note: as you can see this is bugged, the rotation is weird now...)

Answer (score 3):

Click the little lock icon in the top right of the animation window. It will 'lock' the selection (and the animation preview) even when you select something different in the scene or inspector views. (You can also use the lock to have multiple different inspector views.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean for "freeze" the animation? 
Maybe i know what to do:
Press ctrl+6 to open the Animation window
Select the object that you animated
Press the red record button in the animation window 
Select the frame you want to modify
Make your changes 
Press again the red button

Done!

EDIT:

Oh alright then. I've done some investigation about this and i've actually tried it myself. Unfortunately if you are animating an object in unity, and you select another one while animating, the animated object returns to the default position.

I have an idea to solve this problem:

-You put the camera as a child of another gameobject(that you call something like Animation or something similar), create an animation for that gameobject, select the camera object(which is the child) and animate that one instead. all the objects you are going to want to move etc.. must be children of the "Animation" gameobject.

Try this and let me know!

Comment: Next time try to be a little more specific,  tho if you have other problems, ask don't hesitate!

Comment: ok I updated my question with more specific details. I hope you understand the problem now. The problem comes when selecting another object as the animated one.

Comment: I've updated the answer! Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This desirable workflow isn't well supported, but here is my trick for it:

- Create a new camera (name it 'test_cam01' or similar)
- Copy the Camera component values from your original camera (right-click at the top of the component / "Copy Component") + Paste onto new cam's Camera component.
- Make new cam a child of original cam in the hierarchy + zero-out its transform (0s in all Pos and Rot fields and 1s in all scale fields)
- Animate original cam to the spot you want to edit the scene at
- In hierarchy window, remove test cam from original cam (make test cam a child of some other static object in the scene)
- Now, with 'Game' viewport visible, select the test cam, and toggle the 'Camera' component enabled checkbox (not the game object enabled checkbox at the very top of the object, but rather the checkbox ON the camera component itself). Toggling this makes it the active cam for the Game window.

  - You can now edit the scene (just open the scene viewport in a separate spot to use simultaneously), and view it through this static camera without losing your view
  - You can do the same thing with several static test cams along the animation path in order to see views along the way at various points.

GOOD LUCK

Answer (score 0):

This workflow isn't well supported in Unity even in the most recent versions (as of 2022) as the other answers say but there are some tools on the Unity Asset Store that may be-able to help you.

For example: [Editor Animation Freezer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/editoranimationfreezer-222734) on the Unity Asset Store lets you freeze many different Animators in a specific frame in the Editor.